# Comment descender cut off by OP comment color

Tags: bug, comments, design, comment-replies

There's a minor display issue on comments where the OP comment color obscures the bottom pixel of `@`, and presumably other descenders.

Actual size:

> [image]

Enlarged to show texture:

> [image]

Seen on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895299/unsolved-programming-competition?noredirect=1#comment36790422_23895299

Chrome 34 on Windows, at standard 100% zoom

Comment: Doesn't happen in Firefox 29 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'd swear this was asked and answered before.  It's been this way for ages.